# Eclipse maven plugin getting HTTP 416 when retrieving jar

Tags: eclipse, plugins, maven

I'm getting this error in the eclipse logs when I use the maven integration plugin for eclipse in my project:

`Build errors for transport-data; org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) on project transport-data: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:1.0-beta-4, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.13: Failure to transfer org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Failed to transfer http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar. Error code 416, Requested Range Not Satisfiable`

From the browser I can access the jar but how come the plugin gets a 416 status response?

I'm using STS 2.7.2.RELEASE (Eclipse 3.6) with the Maven Integration plugin on Maven 2.2.1
and my OS is Ubuntu 10.10. If someone could please help explain this mystery to me I'd be very grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I know that this is a very old request, but I just came across it too.  What worked for me was deleting the relevant downloaded components in the .m2 repository.  I figured that there may be some partially-loaded bits in there as I had used both Eclipse and command line with maven.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 416 means that the client requested only a portion of the file, but the server probably doesn't support such requests. Though I would be surprised if maven would have broken their repo webserver.
Another possibility is that you are behind a proxy which doesn't support range requests.

Comment: Thanks Peter, do you know of how I can fix this problem? So far I've had to manually download and install the jars in my local repo.